# Unable to build GDAL Visual Studio project with "generate_vcxproj.bat"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, gdal

I need to link GDAL library to a c++ project.

I use the instruction from here:
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GeneratingVisualStudioProject

1. Download gdal231.zip from [official web site](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource). Unpack.
2. (this step may be omitted — result will be the same) Edit nmake.opt by adding this in the very top of the file:

   MSVC_VER=1910

   WIN64=1

(don't know if it's right; there is no thorough guide)

3. Run win cmd, type "generate_vcxproj.bat 15.0 64 gdal_vs2017", wait for finish.
4. Open gdal_vs2017.vcxproj with MSVS Community 15.8.4. Build solution.

Build failed with "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory".

Project settings look strange:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AVuB.png)

"VC++ Directories" seem normal, except $(VC_SourcePath) in "Library Directories":
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bObB.png)

What's wrong with it?

Comment: You should check the include directories and lib directories, under VC++ directories.

Comment: **Felice Pollano**, I just added another screenshot. VC directories are mostly the same as in default-created "Hello World" project.

Comment: You should find under the VC programs / tool a so called developer command prompt, or something like that: try to launch the build from that command prompt.

Comment: You mean, do as I described above, but use "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" instead of win cmd (in step 3)? It makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

In order to build GDAL one doesn't need a Visual Studio project. Don't know what's wrong with "generate_vcxproj" script — it just does'nt work. But there is another way.

1. Unpack gdal231.zip.
2. Launch "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017" (or whatever version of VS command prompt that suits your needs). cd to "gdal-2.3.1\" dir.
3. Open nmake.opt file. In it's beginning there are some hints for usage of makefile.vc. Pick some arguments from there. I opt for x64 release build, so my call to nmake was like that: "nmake -f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1910 WIN64=1". (1910 is a version of Visual Studio 2017).
4. Switch to "Native tools command prompt" and type "nmake -f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1910 WIN64=1" there. Enter.
5. When it's finished, type "nmake -f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1910 WIN64=1 install" and press Enter.
6. When that's finished too, type "nmake -f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1910 WIN64=1 devinstall" and press Enter.
7. Done. The library is in C:\warmerda\bld\ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when building with VS2017 Community Edition.  I was able to build fine using VS2015 Community Edition.

Bottom line: when running the .bat, use the 2015 option.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the generate_vcxproj.bat file using the information from here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering

I modified mine to work with Visual Studio Community 2019 by modifying lines 55-70 to be this:

```
if "%_vcver_%"=="16.2" (
    set _clver_=1922
    set _vstoolset_=v1422
) else if "%_vcver_%"=="15.0" (
    set _clver_=1910
    set _vstoolset_=v141
) else if "%_vcver_%"=="14.0" (
    set _clver_=1900
    set _vstoolset_=v140
) else ( if "%_vcver_%"=="12.0" (
    set _clver_=1800
    set _vstoolset_=v120
) else (
    echo Wrong value for parameter 1. See usage:
    goto :usage
))
```